# Best way to emulate IIS under Debian?

Tags: iis, debian

I client of mine needs IIS with .NET for his project. I want to make this on Linux machine, but how to emulate it without virtual machine? What is so specific in IIS that can`t be found in Debian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, it's called .NET. That's a Microsoft technology, included in IIS. That's what can't be found in Debian. It's possible that your application could run under Mono as-is or with minor re-writes. But even simple things like the path delimiter are different between the operating systems.